# sym linking iTunes Media -> Music to external thumb drive

Tags: itunes, hard-drive, symlink

I'm out of space on my Macbook Air and thinking about ways of removing things. One idea is to put all my music (~100GB) on a big thumb drive (y, and back it up). I pretty much always have my keychain so this is only a slight inconvencience. I would symlink that directory to a folder on the thumb drive. Has anyone done this? I know some people won't like the idea due to thumb drive irreliability but I have had good luck.

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually change the location that iTunes stores its library under Preferences -> Advanced -> iTunes Media folder Location.

In that case, you could migrate your iTunes library to that external drive. You would just need to make sure you have the drive connected when wanting to use iTunes.

You may want to be careful with carrying this much on a thumb drive (if they even make them that large). As in, its easy to loose, get damaged, etc - so make sure you have a backup.

Another good way to do this would be to just use an external hard drive connected over firewire or USB.